# Error uploading file in Laravel: Call to a member function on null

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

I want to upload a file in laravel.

I have used this code in controller:

```
function store1(Request $request){
    $file=$request->file('myfile');
    $folder=$request->file('folder');
    $link=$request->input('link');

    $filename1 = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename2 = $folder->getClientOriginalName();

    //$projectname
    $path="files/";
   $file->move($path,$filename1);
   $folder->move($path,$filename2);

   DB::table('groups')->update(['last_report'=>$filename1,'DropBox'=>$filename2]);

    return view('successfulUpload');
}
```

I want to enable user to upload more than one file but it shows Call to a member function `getClientOriginalName()` on null.

Comment: try to var_dump($file, $folder) and let us know what is there

Comment: Seems no file is uploaded there. Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form ?

Comment: I already put  enctype="multipart/form-data" in myform

Comment: for multiple uplaods, you will get an array of files and then you will have to loop into it
look here
http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this for multiple upload in Laravel.

The HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="controller/function" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In your controller:

```
        // get posted input file
        $files = Input::file('files');
        $errors = "";
        $file_data = array();

        foreach($files as $file) 
        {

            if(Input::hasFile('files'))
            {
              // validating each file.
              $rules = array('file' => 'required'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
              $validator = Validator::make(

                    [
                        'file' => $file,
                        'extension'  => Str::lower($file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
                    ],
                    [
                        'file' => 'required|max:100000',
                        'extension'  => 'required|in:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,doc,docx,zip,rar,pdf,rtf,xlsx,xls,txt'
                    ]
                );

              if($validator->passes())
              {

                // path is root/uploads
                $destinationPath = 'path/to/upload';
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

                $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

                if($upload_success) 
                {

                   //do after success ....

                } 
                else 
                {
                   $errors .= json('error', 400);
                }


              } 
              else 
              {
                // redirect back with errors.
                return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
              }
            }

        }
```